# For loop in conditional statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, foreach

I have script in box-in-box manner if statement sequence:

```
if($(selected).children('li').children('ul')){
  selected = $(selected).children('li').children('ul');
  $(selected).attr('data-level','3');

  if( $(selected).children('li').children('ul')  ){
    selected = $(selected).children('li').children('ul');
    $(selected).attr('data-level','4');

    if( $(selected).children('li').children('ul')  ){
      selected = $(selected).children('li').children('ul');
      $(selected).attr('data-level','5');

      if( $(selected).children('li').children('ul')  ){
        selected = $(selected).children('li').children('ul');
        $(selected).attr('data-level','6');

        if( $(selected).children('li').children('ul')  ){
          selected = $(selected).children('li').children('ul');
          $(selected).attr('data-level','7');
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I just wonder how to handle this in a simple for loop. Thanks for any help.

Comment: All the conditions will always pass in that snippet. You need to check `length` of the returned jQuery object.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. Where is the first `selected` coming from for a start Why can you just group all the `data-level` change under one if statement? Agh, confused of Tonbridge.

Comment: Note for down voters: The fact that code doesn't make any sense for you, doesn't mean that you fully understood the question. Downvoting shouldn't be that easy ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like that:

```js
$('ul').attr('data-level', function () {
    return $(this).parents('ul').length;
});
```

```css
[data-level="0"] {
    color: blue;
}
[data-level="1"] {
    color: green;
}
[data-level="2"] {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li>3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```